# scroll to follow as elements are dynamically added

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

(FYI this is for an art project so it won't sound like a reasonable thing to do on a website)

I have jquery code that goes down through the dom and adds an attribute ('bar') to random elements on the page.  I'd like the new elements to scroll into view as they are added.  i've tried a few things, most recently using :eq() to identify the last such element on the page but no dice.

```
        var last = $('[bar]').length;
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('[bar]:eq('+last+')').offset().top }, 100);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Here's my guess at something like what you are trying to do:

```js
var bar_ids = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

var myInterval;
var myIndex = 0;
var myLoopCount = 0;


myInterval = setInterval(()=>{
  if (myLoopCount == 0){
    var att = document.createAttribute("bar"); 
    document.querySelector('#'+bar_ids[myIndex]).setAttributeNode(att);
  }  
  bars = $('[bar]');
  //console.log(bars[myIndex])
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(bars[myIndex]).offset().top }, 1000);
  myIndex +=1;
  if (myIndex >= bar_ids.length){
    myLoopCount += 1;
    myIndex = 0;
    if (myLoopCount > 5){
      clearInterval(myInterval)
    }    
  }
},500)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one" style="height:1200px; background:#ff0000"></div>
<div id="two" style="height:1200px; background:#0004ff"></div>
<div id="three" style="height:1200px; background:#00ff04"></div>
```

Give me some more source code and description I can probably help further.

The best would be if you would fork this codePen: https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/qBdrQLG and then share that too :)

**In short**, (assuming I guessed your use case close/well enough) you should use a selector like this:

`$(bars[myIndex]).offset().top`

And you could get the bars (array of DOM elements) like this:

`var bars = $('[bar]');`

and you could get myIndex like:

`var myIndex = bars.length - 1;` (remember arrays are zero-indexed)

Comment: thanks!  the entire problem was solved by subtracting 1 from var last, forgot about zero-indexing!